# iText API for PDF comparison

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Can I use iText API for comparing two PDF files? I have gone through various approaches on stackoverflow for comparing PDF files such as tools, some utilities such as imagemagick etc. 
The PDFs which I wish to compare are fiancial reports with graphs, tables and text etc.
We have to compare a large number of files and would like to do it through command line utility. There is a ComparePDF command line tool but its just outputs whether two files are conatining differences. We will like to print a log of file differences. Can we accomplish this through iText?

Comment: Do you want to compare text containing in the PDF ?

Comment: I see multiple comments / answers asking you to clarify your question, but the details don't come. As it is now nearly two months old I assume you either found a solution or gave up... If you did find a solution, posting it here for for future reference would be cool. You could do something back for others looking for answers to this. As it stands I gave the question a -1. Unclear and no feedback to the people trying to help you.

Comment: I understand and apologize. We still have not found any solution. We thought iText could achieve it but as the comments sugested u need to use a combination of technologies to achieve this. I did not get enough time after this to do more research. One thing on  my mind is trying modifying the code of diffpdf tool so that it can be automaticly called for a large number of files. The tool is nice and does what we need but its UI has not been automated.

Answer (score 7):

What do you want to compare? iText could be used to compare structure and syntax, but... two different PDFs that look identical to the human eye, may have a completely different structure and syntax internally.

At iText, we have written JUnit tests that use GhostScript to create images of each page. These images are compared to each other on a pixel per pixel basis.

We also use iText in JUnit tests, but these tests look at the structure and the syntax more than at the content.

Comment: Good One +1 for the answer.

Comment: we want to compare PDFs visually...as in how it looks to the human eye...font size, text position, alignment etc....yes I had read that two PDFs that look alike may be remarkably different internaly. I have checked DiffPDF tool. But we want to compare a large number of reports in automated manner. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: So what level of reporting do you want? You mention that you want more detail - what do you want to report back to the user? Number of differences? Percentage? An image? There are (often commercial) tools available but most of them have a very specific way to report that might not be what you are looking for...

Comment: @GordanWebb How identical do you expect the documents to be? Shall they really, pixel by pixel, be identical? Are slight shifts of the whole page allowed? May text paragraphs be slightly reflowed? May Colorspaces differ? What about the document properties?

Comment: its not possible to predict how idential documents will be. we would like to generate detailed log reports...specifying what the difference is..e.g. if two table values are not matching then page header, table header, column name, row name etc.. these will be present on the page itself....can this be accomplished?

Comment: @GordanWebb (please add notification tags where appropriate) You will have to specify the requirements more exactly. E.g. "in the rectangular area A expect text T in font F right aligned" or "there is a table with dividing lines at x coordinates x1, x2, x3... and at y coordinates y1, y2, y3; expect identical (text) in the table cells in documents D1 and D2". What kinds of such criteria do you want?

Comment: Yes ...currently our team compares those files manually and generates a log in which differences are listed...here are the examples - "Page 3 Performance Review Footnotes text difference", "Page 4 Performance Review Footnotes appear on the next page", "Page 8 Sector Analysis Footnotes text missing" ...can we achieve this through code? I am doubtful..but then something that is close? Kindly guide me.

Comment: I think you'll always need a combination of tools. For instance: start with something similar to what we do: render pages with gs and compare the images. If there's a difference, parse the page with iText and compare the textual content. It's not easy to achieve this.

Comment: @GordanWebb Your examples are very aware of contextual connections of separate text sections, especially the footnote related ones. You either have to put much specific knowledge of the report format into your code (e.g. your code "knows" there have to be footnotes number 4, 5, and 6 on the bottom of page 4), or you must put much intelligence into it to recognize footnotes references in the text as such (and not to mistake e.g. exponents in formulas, y = x², or units, 15 m³, for such references).

Comment: can you point me to a good resource ( book, tutorial, website etc) where I can learn the basics of these things? Additionally we checked this tool DiffPDF(http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html) in detail. In this there is a functionality to save a third output pdf where both the input files are shown side by side with differences highlighted. If we cant produce the detailed logs, even the automation of the process of generating this third file can help us a great deal. Let me know if you have had a look at this tool.

Comment: @GordanWebb (Please use notification tags; I found your comment here only by accident. Or was your comment only directed at Bruno?) To get a first impression what you actually deal with, simply have a look at the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), especially chapters 8 and 9. No, you don't have to implement directly that spec, that's what any decent PDF library does for you. You should have a look at that to know what kind of information there actually is in a PDF and, thus, to compare in multiple PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the  Myers O(ND) diff algorithm  for PDF comparison , itext or pdfbox api dont provide the method for pdf comparison , you can extract the text of these files and coordinates using itext , later use the  Myers O(ND) diff algorithm to find the difference and highlight the changes.