# Making the PDF format readable and diff-able

Tags: pdf, comparison, integration-testing, meta, human-readable

I am wondering if anyone have thought of a way to display the PDF document format in a more human readable form?

Now, to compare PDF files, or see exactly what have changed between to versions is very difficult. Many changes aren't visible to the naked eye since they are not a part of the graphical representation(as "created when", and similar).

So if a PDF is a result of an integration test, it is difficult to find the problem without a hex-editor. Also, it is difficult to disregard "created when" in the comparison.

I am not talking any interpretation and displaying, just converting the basic object types to some meta-language. For simplicity's sake, let's say XML. And name nodes like they are named in the PDF specification.

There are PDF-parsers available for most programming languages. Still, at least I, can't find anyone that have gone the distance to convert it to something readable.

Or have I missed it?

Edit:
To clarify(example from specification):

```
BI % Begin inline image object
  /W 17 % Width in samples
  /H 17 % Height in samples
  /CS /RGB % Color space
  /BPC 8 % Bits per component
  /F [ /A85 /LZW ] % Filters
```

Would become:

```
<BI>
  <W>17</W>
  <H>17</H>
  <CS><RGB/></CS>
  <BPC>8</BPC>
  <F>
    <item>A85</item>
    <item>LZW</item>
  </F>
</BI>
```

..and so on.

Binary data could either be extracted to a file or just show a hash or size.

Comment: Not really possible. A pure-text pdf MAY be simply diffable, because the text content is literally embedded within the PDF as-is. But a graphic of text is a whole different beast. a one pixel difference in one letter can cause multiple neighboring pixels to shift values as well, leading to a huge cascade of differences, even though only one actual pixel was changed. And since PDFs are essentially just postscript programs, the exact same content can have totally different pdf representations, depending on your "compiler" decided to build the pdf file.

Comment: I am just interested in diff:ing the output file, not the effect a certain difference may have, that comes later.
Graphics are binary, so that one have changed is sufficient information to know that it is involved in the difference somehow. That way I can find the regression. Or have I gotten it wrong?

The text is also almost never the problem. The problem is usually that a PDF report generator has decided to move an object two pixels to the right, or something.

Comment: And to clarify, I am actually interested in tracking down differences in how the pdf "compiler" operates in given situations, as those differences can cause problems when a user renders the given PDF file.

Comment: Check out what the creator of iText (a PDF library) says: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13703359/231316

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll check that out.

Comment: We, at our company, have worked out a simple MFC application to browse pds (its objects and xrefs). It's definitely for pre-1.7 pdfs. And you have to diff yourself by examining the object in each xref. But it is posible...

Comment: Yeah I agree, I think that is the way to go. 
I will try and cook up a Python application that dumps everything neatly, posts a link here when I am done.